# IOError: Can't read data (Can't open directory) - Missing gzip compression filter

Tags: python, linux, hdf5, anaconda, h5py

I have never worked with HDF5 files before, and to get started I received some example files. I've been checking out all the basics with `h5py`, looking at the different groups in these files, their names, keys, values and so on. Everything works fine, until I want to look at the datasets that are saved in the groups. I get their `.shape` and `.dtype`, but when I try accessing a random value by indexing (e.g. `grp["dset"][0]`), I get the following error:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-509cebb66565> in <module>()
      1 print geno["matrix"].shape
      2 print geno["matrix"].dtype
----> 3 geno["matrix"][0]

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.pyc in __getitem__(self, args)
    443         mspace = h5s.create_simple(mshape)
    444         fspace = selection._id
--> 445         self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype)
    446
    447         # Patch up the output for NumPy

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5d.so in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read (h5py/h5d.c:2782)()

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_proxy.so in h5py._proxy.dset_rw (h5py/_proxy.c:1709)()

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_proxy.so in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread (h5py/_proxy.c:1379)()

IOError: Can't read data (Can't open directory)
```

I've posted this problem in the [h5py Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/m_Sqt2qZNQk), where it was suggested that there might be a filter on the dataset I don't have installed. But the HDF5 file was created using only gzip compression, which should be a portable standard, as far as I understood.
Does someone know what I might be missing here? I can't even find a description of this error or similar problems anywhere, and the file, including the problematic dataset, can be easily opened with the HDFView software.

**Edit**
Apparently, this error occurs because, for some reason, the gzip compression filter is not available on my system. If I try to create an example file with gzip compression, this happens:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-dd7b9e3b6314> in <module>()
      1 grp = f.create_group("subgroup")
----> 2 grp_dset = grp.create_dataset("dataset", (50,), dtype="uint8", chunks=True, compression="gzip")

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.pyc in create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
     92         """
     93 
---> 94         dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
     95         dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
     96         if name is not None:

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.pyc in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times)
     97 
     98     dcpl = filters.generate_dcpl(shape, dtype, chunks, compression, compression_opts,
---> 99                   shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, scaleoffset)
    100 
    101     if fillvalue is not None:

/home/sarah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/filters.pyc in generate_dcpl(shape, dtype, chunks, compression, compression_opts, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, scaleoffset)
    101 
    102         if compression not in encode:
--> 103             raise ValueError('Compression filter "%s" is unavailable' % compression)
    104 
    105         if compression == 'gzip':

ValueError: Compression filter "gzip" is unavailable
```

Does anyone have experience with that? The installation of the HDF5 library as well as the h5py package didn't seem to go wrong...

Comment: That looks like an incorrect path/permissions problem to me.

Comment: Is `dset` among the dataset names listed by `grp.keys()`?  Do you have a sample file you can post somewhere for us to see?  Also consider doing `h5ls thefile` on the command line and see what that shows.

Comment: Please could you post the output of `print geno["matrix"]`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, the dataset appears in the groups keys. The `h5ls` command lists the two groups that are in the file.
@Yossarian The output of just `print geno["matrix"]` is `<HDF5 dataset "matrix": shape (1008, 11623), type "|u1">`.

Comment: This seems pretty strange.  Any chance you can upload an example file somewhere which exhibits the issue for other people to try it out?  Ideally a file not super-huge in size.

Comment: I tried creating an example file, but couldn't (see my edited question). Apparently the whole problem is that I'm missing the gzip compression filter, but I don't understand how this could have happened.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Have you resolved it eventually?

Comment: I think it was solved by Anaconda changing something in the h5py package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't just comment - reputation too low.

I had the same issue, simply ran "conda update anaconda" and the problem is gone.

Comment: That makes sense. Over at the h5py Google group, we figured that there was something wrong with the Anaconda h5py version, and they fixed it there. Thanks for reminding me to close the issue here as well!

Answer (score 9):

This error happens when `h5py` can't find the plugin it needs to open the file. For many of the common plugins, this can be solved by adding:

```
import hdf5plugin
```

before you use the h5py library. You don't have to use the `hdf5plugin` library directly, you just import it. Different imports may work for you depending on which plugin the file is using - it would be helpful if this error message were a bit more descriptive.

Comment: had the same issue. This suggestion fixed it

Comment: this is crazy that you have to do this!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it with

`import tables`

and it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue,

```
$ python3 -c 'import h5py; f=h5py.File("file.h5"); d=f["FVC"][:,:]'                                                               

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_objects.c:2696)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_objects.c:2654)
  File "/home/pinaultf/system/anaconda2/envs/deveg-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 482, in __getitem__
    self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_objects.c:2696)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_objects.c:2654)
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 181, in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/h5d.c:3240)
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 130, in h5py._proxy.dset_rw (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_proxy.c:1869)
  File "h5py/_proxy.pyx", line 84, in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread (/home/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/work/h5py/_proxy.c:1517)
OSError: Can't read data (Can't open directory)
```

I had this problem in one virtual environment and not in another, even if apparently the h5py version was the same (2.6.0).

I **solved** this issue with :

```
$ pip uninstall h5py
$ pip install h5py
```

Answer (score -1):

I switched python 3.6 to python 3.8 and 'import tables', solved.