# reading h5 file fails

Tags: python, compression, h5py

I am trying to read an h5 file (compressed using gzip) on an ec2 (ubuntu) using h5py. I try accessing the file like so:

```
contents = {}
with h5py.File(h5py_file, 'r') as f:
    for key in enumerate f.keys():
        contents[key] = np.array(f.get(key))
```

However this gives me the following error:
`IOError: Can't read data (Can't open directory)`

The code works fine on my local machine. I have also checked that I can access the file properly and that it has the correct permissions. I'm now thinking that it might be related to the compression, however I do have gzip installed, so I'm not sure exactly what's going on.

When I remove the conversion to the np array I don't get this error, however I am obviously unable to access the data..

The issue seems to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301346/ioerror-cant-read-data-cant-open-directory-missing-gzip-compression-filte), but I'm not using Anaconda so I'm not sure how to solve it.